# По каким правилам AWS rm bucket удаляет?

Tags: amazon, amazon-web-services

Если я пишу:

```
& aws s3 rm s3://bucket-name/folder/
```

Он не удаляет, говорит что `folder` - это не объект. Если я пишу:

```
& aws s3 rm s3://bucket-name/folder/ --recursive
```

То он удаляет, и всё хорошо, но что будет, если я напишу:

```
& aws s3 rm s3://bucket-name/
```

Ставлю этот вопрос, так как случайно ввел эту команду и потом сразу нажал отмену. Удалил ли он часть моих данных в этом промежутке или нет?

Comment: А в чем проблема взять и проверить, удалилось ли где-то там что-то или нет?

Comment: в том то и дело что там очень много информации , и я не могу проверить.

Answer (score 1):

из [документации](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/rm.html):

---

> The following rm command recursively deletes all objects under a specified bucket and prefix **when passed with the parameter --recursive**. In this example, the bucket mybucket contains the objects test1.txt and test2.txt:

```
aws s3 rm s3://mybucket --recursive
```

> Output:

```
delete: s3://mybucket/test1.txt
delete: s3://mybucket/test2.txt
```

---

ключевые слова выделены. т.е. **без** опции `--recursive` удаляться ничего не будет.

что ещё существенно: сам *bucket* тоже не будет удалён даже при наличии опции `--recursive`.